# regular expressions Negation not working Python

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

So I tried to deny this pattern but it isn't working, even if I wrap it around with (). I assume it's mixing it up with the anchor but I can't find a way to circumvent this issue. I checked in other questions but didn't find a solution for my specific issue :/

The idea is to get only the cases that not match latitude/longitude number sequences.

```
[i for i in [re.findall(r"^\-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+", string) for string in real_state['latitude']]]
```

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3dLw.png)

Comment: Can you also include what your data looks like, what you are getting and what you want? I

Comment: I'm getting the correct match but I want the negation, so I can find the cases where it doesn't match

Comment: `^` is not a negation outside of the group construct.  It signifies the "start of line" instead. What you might want to do is `[i for i in real_state['latitude'] if re.search(r"\-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+", i) is None)` but it's hard to tell without sample data.

Comment: Try  `re.split(r"-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+", string)`

Comment: @Idlehands that worked but it didn't solve completely my issue. Regardless, thanks for that way because in the future it'll be useful.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that kinda solved my immediate issue and I managed to get what I needed. Not sure if it will be a long term solution but for now it works! Thank you :)

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please consider also upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) as after reaching 15 rep points you are entitled to upvoting privilege.

Comment: Didn't know I could do that. Thanks for the tip. Done ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest splitting the string with your pattern:

```
import re
s = "Text: 0.12345 and -12.34433 and more to come"
results = re.split(r"\s*-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\s*", s)
print(results)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/5XyRhx).

In case there appear any empty items, like in cases the matches appear at the start/end of the string, remove them with `filter`:

```
import re
s = "0.12345 and -12.34433 and more to come 0.54321 and -27.87654"
results = re.split(r"\s*-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\s*", s)
# print(results)                   # => ['', 'and', 'and more to come', 'and', '']
print(list(filter(None, results))) # => ['and', 'and more to come', 'and']
```

See [another Python demo](https://ideone.com/AdG406).

Comment: Filter helps out removing the empty spaces generated by re.split so thanks for the that!